# JPA Query is not throwing any errors and I keep getting only null

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm fairly new to Spring and JPA.
I have a User entity:

```
package com.cooksys.twitter.entities;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Table(name = "user_table")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    @Embedded
    private Credentials credentials;
    
    @Embedded
    private Profile profile;
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp joined;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tweet> tweets;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "likes")
    private List<Tweet> likedTweets;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "following")
    private List<User> followers;

    
    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> following;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userMentioned")
    private List<Tweet> mentions;

    @Column
    private boolean deleted;
}
```

I have a Credentials entity:

```
package com.cooksys.twitter.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Embeddable
public class Credentials {
    
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String username;
    
    private String password;
}
```

I have my UserRepository:

```
package com.cooksys.twitter.repositories;

import com.cooksys.twitter.entities.Credentials;
import com.cooksys.twitter.entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByCredentials(Credentials credentials);
    User findByCredentials_Username(String username);
    User findByCredentialsUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

I'm getting passed in a TweetRequestDto that has Credentials inside with a username and password. Now when I pass those credentials into my repository query :

```
User user = userRepository.findByCredentials_Username(tweetRequestDto.getCredentials().getUsername());
```

or any variation of the queries in my repository, I only get returned null. I know the credentials are correct and in the database.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In your UserRepository, have you tried defining User findByUsername(String username);  ?

Comment: From a cursory glance, this looks to be correct.  You can get a closer look at what's going on behind the scenes by adding the property, `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`.  It might help you hone in on what's going on

Comment: Yes, thank you for your guys responses! 
I was given a Seeder.java class to populate my data when initially writing my code. Everything worked from the seed data. But, I didn't realize from my test environment in Postman that the tests had to be run sequentially. So, my  teammate had to finish making his User class and pass the tests in order for me to run my tweet tests.